# When I click the button, I can't work with app anymore until it ends

Tags: c#, windows

I created a C# Windows application that has a lot of code behind its button.
When I click this button, I can't do anything in my app anymore until the end of the process.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Without looking at your code it's difficult to suggest anything. Wherever operation you are doing in button click can be done asynchronously and you can still interact with UI. You can Google around it there are plenty of examples available

Comment: Please edit your question by adding codes that may be hang your application.

Comment: @ShadyBoshra there are about 2000 lines of code
i know i should write some code at the start but i dont know what

Comment: @amirsalar, so you have to use breakpoints to know where exactly the execution of application is stopped or hanged. And if you didn't know to solve it, please provide any suspicious codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start a new thread on button click, and keep free your main threat. You can handle it using the delegate.